# Setting environment in Dockerfile not reflecting in docker exec

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Having trouble with setting environment in docker.

My Dockerfile has the following line:

```
ENV abc=hello
```

I build the docker image using:

```
 docker image build --no-cache -t foobar .
```

Run the container in daemon mode:

```
 docker run -it -d foobar
```

Run `docker container ls`, find the container name and run:

```
docker exec -it suspicious_poincare echo $abc
```

It doesn't print "hello". Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
docker exec -it suspicious_poincare bash -c "echo \$abc"
```

If don't do this,it will echo environment from your host.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're trying to run is Chained command thus first command is being executed by container and second one is being executed by your host machine. Therefore, like @heydar-dasoomi suggested, you need to run in inside quotes the commands. Please read the discussion of Docker repo from following link https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/119.

Comment: Please give some more explanation of how the link answers the question.  The GitHub issue describes the behavior is pretty clearly and it is distinctly not a Docker bug.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've edited my comment and gave some more explanation.